# How to make google cloud's wordpress template accessible to the public?

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, debian, firewall

I deployed a VM with wordpress already installed and I was able to access initially. It appears that after some time web traffic is blocked if using the external IP address.

I tried allowing http/https from the google admin dashboard as well as adding those rules to IPTABLES in the debian instance but I'm still unable to access when using the external IP address.

Here is my IPTABLE -L output:

root@wordpress-2-vm:/home/myname# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Comment: I've also tried changing the keep alive: sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)